# cd : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\hp\prometheus' because it does not exist

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm

PS C:\Users\hp> helm pull prometheus-community/prometheus
I ran this cmd on my windows terminal and then I'm unable to change the directory ie:
cd prometheus.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OvO2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simply pulling the helm chart would download a bundled tarball to your workstation

In order to inspect the chart files, it is possible to use this option :

```
--untar                      if set to true, will untar the chart after downloading it
```

Ref: https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_pull/#helm-pull

You can always list the existing files under the current directories ( `dir` command ) to see what is there, and then you can change directory accordingly